# Prove that $f(A)$ is a separable subset

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $f: (M,d) \rightarrow (N,\rho)$ be continuous and let $A$ be a separable subset of M. Prove that $f(A)$ is separable.

My idea is to take countable dense subset of A and then construct an open ball for its points and use the definition of continuity in a metric space to conclude that $f(A)$ is separable.

Kindly help me to provide a rigorous proof.

Thanks!

Comment: @G.Chiusole When $A$ is said to be a separable subset. What does it mean ? 1. A is a Countable Dense subset in M. or 2. A has a countable dense subset. If it is the later than how should I proceed ?

Comment: It means the latter. Proceed as is done in the question linked and the use the comments to the question (or the first answer). I the question I linked, $X$ is the separable subset ($A$ in your case) and $A$ is the countable dense subset